# Blank pages when deleting content in TYPO3

Tags: typo3, backend

I recently migrated my TYPO3 Installation from Linux to Windows server. Everything seems to be working fine except when I edit pages in the backend and I go to delete content from a page, instead of refreshing the page after the change, it just displays a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of things that could cause this error. In order to solve it

- Delete temporaray files (`typo3conf/temp_*`)
- Check your PHP/Apache Error Log for any hints
- Make sure all Extensions are up-to-date (in your case it might be TemplaVoila)
- clear all caches in the backend